# Using Svelte, how do I populate a <style> tag in <svelte:head> with a Javascript string variable?

Tags: svelte, sapper, css-in-js

Using Svelte, what I want to accomplish is being able to style my `html` using the `css` property of a `post` object I have.

I thought, no problem, just add a style tag to my `svelte:head` with `{post.css}`. It will drop my `post.css` data right into the style tag, and viola’, problem solved. But, no, problem not solved. When I view the element in my browser, I see

`<style>{post.css}</style>`

instead of

```
<style>
  p{
    color: purple;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
 </style>
```

I have created a work around, where I set the `innerText` of the `<style>` tag after `onMount`, but I don’t like it, and would prefer to do it a cleaner way.

What I want…

```
<script>
  export let post = {
    html: `<p>This is purple</p>`,
    css : `
      p{
        color: purple;
        font-weight: 900;
      }
    `
    }  
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <style>{post.css}</style>
</svelte:head>

{@html post.html}
```

What I have to do to make it work…

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  export let post = {
    html: `<p>This is purple</p>`,
    css : `
      p{
        color: purple;
        font-weight: 900;
      }
    `
    }

  onMount(() => {
    let styler = document.getElementById("styler");
    styler.innerText = post.css
  });
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <style id="styler"></style>
</svelte:head>

{@html post.html}
```

If you have any other alternatives to using the `css` property to style the `html` property of the `post` object, or know how to get Svelte to recognize `{post.css}` in a `<style>` tag, please let me know.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this:

```html
{@html `<style>${post.css}</style>`}
```

Bear in mind that the styles in `post.css` will apply to the entire page, not just to the post's HTML.

[Demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/9bf8c612228c4ce1b5bff414319583e4?version=3.16.0)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in SvelteKit. I'm getting

Error while preprocessing `src/routes/__layout.svelte:1:3`: Unknown word

Comment: @Casimir If there's a postcss preprocessor in your stack, it can give you the "Unknown word" error. In that case, split up the `style` tag into 2 strings like ``{@html `<`+`style>${post.css}</style>`}``